# Xcode cloud data center location

Tags: xcode-cloud

Do we have a documentation that says where xcode cloud stores your data or if you can change regions? Most cloud solutions like AWS and Google allows selecting region.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just got back from an xcode lab.

> Apple: Currently it is only in US. It is optimised for integration
> with App Store connect so it should be as close/as fast as it can be.